# For/in loop not working in java script

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
function myFunction()
{
  var x;
  var txt="";
  var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25};  
  for (x in person) 
  {
    txt=txt + person[x];  
  }  

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt; 
}  

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This function should display one property of the object `person` every time the button is clicked (first "John", then "Doe", and finally 25). However, the first time the button is clicked, the output is JohnDoe25. How can this function be modified so that it fits the requirement?

Comment: Umm... what?  What's the question here?  What's the problem?  What does this do?  Do you see any errors?  Have you debugged on your own?

Comment: `txt = quotes.join('')`?

Comment: thanks WOLF its ok but i want in another way that's means first one should disapper and senond one come and again i click then second one moved and third one come in this way i want.

Comment: hello ROCKET HAZMAT now you get what i want

Comment: "JavaScript Object properties have no inherent order" You should use array as your first attempt   http://jsfiddle.net/s8w5E/2/

Comment: thank's wolf now i get what i want

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use array but in your case,
Yo can do it like this: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUM7/1/)**

```
<script>
var x = 0;
var txt="";
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe","age":25}; 
function myFunction(){
    if(x==0){
        txt = person['fname']; 
    }
    if(x==1){
        txt = person['lname'];
    }
    if(x==2){
       txt = person['age']; 
    }
    x++;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt; 
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```